# Dell 3721 display problem Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, dell, display

After I upgrade from ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04 I can't change the brightness of the display, it remain in the darkest possible mode. I have a Dell 3721 laptop. Any advice?

```
@Dell:~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
```

Comment: Sadly nobody can answer my question, but I found a part of the solution by myself.  echo 4000 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness will bright my display enought, but I can only change the level if I use the terminal and change this 4000 to another number. I cant use the keys or the brightness control of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this. Success was reported with this solution on the 3721.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2148814

Comment: Please summarize the link's key points with your answer.